# Mongodb string connection to pod

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, countly-analytics

I'm trying to install the countly application on k8s. 
Countly needs mongodb to be able to write the data and I'm trying to configure the connection string.

```
      - name: COUNTLY_CONFIG_API_MONGODB
        value: "mongodb://mongo-mongodb-statefulset.mongo-mongodb-statefulset:27017/countly?mongodb-0"
```

currently when i going to see the log on the **mongodb** pod  it said `waiting for connections on port 27017`

however when i watch the log on the countly pod i got

```
2020-04-05T21:52:10.289Z: ERROR [db:read]   Error reading plugins {"name":"findOne","args":[{"_id":"plugins"},null]} MongoParseError: Incomplete key value pair for option {"name":"MongoParseError"}
2020-04-05T21:52:10.290Z: ERROR [db:read]   Error reading plugins {"name":"findOne","args":[{"_id":"plugins"},null]} MongoParseError: Incomplete key value pair for option {"name":"MongoParseError"}
2020-04-05T21:52:10.290Z: ERROR [db:write]  Error writing sessions_ {"name":"replaceOne","args":[{"_id":"16aCG-ceXPidlM5yDvoJn4wBRQGTy"},{"_id":"16aCG-ceXPidlM5yDvoJn4wBRQGTy","session":"{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86400000,\"expires\":\"2020-04-06T21:52:10.290Z\",\"secure\":false,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"csrfSecret\":\"NmOJ6Tki4LKeonLCborIYVxL\"}","expires":"2020-04-06T21:52:10.290Z"},{"upsert":true},null]} MongoParseError: Incomplete key value pair for option {"name":"MongoParseError"}
MongoParseError: Incomplete key value pair for option
```

do you know how i can test my connection string ?

*i'dont have access to a terminal :(*

Answer (score 1):

The error says `Incomplete key value pair for option`, that's because you have `?mongodb-0` in the end which is treated as a key, but it doesn't have a value. Just remove it and it should work assuming the address itself is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a MongoDB instance running? The Mongo URL doesn't look like a valid URL (unlikely namespace name). If you don't have a mongo instance, create a Deploymant and Service using

```
kubectl create deploy mymongodb --image=mongo
kubectl create service clusterip mymongodb --tcp=27017
```

The MongoDB intance should be available at

```
mongodb://mymongodb:27017
```

For serious use cases, adjust Deployment manifest with auth, etc. or use Helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

i fix my issue with the mongo string connection : 
.

```
"mongodb://mongo-0.mongo,mongo-1.mongo:27017/dbname_?"
```

i hope this will help someone